# Given an asychronous block, how to know when the block will be completed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks

Suppose you are using an asynchronous block from the `ALAssetsLibrary` API such as `enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)`. First off, Since the block is asynchronous, does this mean the system will automatically run the block on a separate thread of execution? If so, what is the best way to know when the block will be completed so I could perform some action like stopping an `UIActivityIndicator` from spinning or reloading a `UITableView`. IE like the `animateWithDuration` block which has a completion block that allows you to perform some action when the animation is complete. What is the pattern for doing something similar here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A block will usually run on your main thread, the function that you are calling is the asynchronous part. The block is often used to know when the function you called asynchronously is completed. In this particular case, a quick look at the [reference material](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) tells us that:

> The block to invoke using each asset in turn. When the enumeration is
>   done, enumerationBlock is invoked with group set to nil.

So in this case just look for that nil!

EDIT:

To check for nil try something like this

```
ALAssetsLibrary *lib = [ALAssetsLibrary new];
[lib enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll 
                   usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
                       if (group == nil) {
                           NSLog(@"Done!");
                       }
                   } 
                 failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                     NSLog(@"Failed...");
                 }
 ];
```

And if you want to check if you are currenty on the main thread you can use:

```
 NSLog("On main thread : %d",[NSThread isMainThread] ? 1:0);
```

In API calls like this the block in run on the main thread because they are not the "heavy lifting" part of the function. They code that could potentially lock up your UI is still done in the background. In this particular case, its more that the function is "coming back up for air" and asking you what you want done for the given group, and then it goes back in the background.

Comment: Thanks. So do you mean a block within an asynchronous method will usually be called on the main thread? Also, do you know the syntax to do the latter part of what you're saying, ie checking if the block is nil? I assume that should be done outside of the block, but if I'm just sitting there waiting for when the block will be nil, aren't I negating the advantages of the asynchronous thread?

Comment: You 'can' execute a block on a background thread (NSThread performBlockInBackground will do it), but the point of block in most of these API functions is to allow you some control over the asynchronous execution. The animation APIs for example will give you a completion block back on the main thread. I'm unfamiliar with this set of API, so why don't you check to make sure. Use [NSThread isMainThread] in an NSLog() to print out if you are on the main thread or not in the block calls. Check the edit for your other questions

Comment: What a bizarre convention (at least in this case, where a synchronous call would likely be more convenient for most users).  But I guess there are no straightforward alternatives on the implementation side of things than making a spurious iteration with a `nil` sigil.